Line break inside psfrag
I want to replace a tag with some text inside an .eps graphic using \psfrag. Is there any way to replace the tag with multi line text? I tried \psfrag{tag}{line 1 \\ line 2} and \psfrag{tag}{line 1 \newline line 2} but it did not work so far.
Thanks for your help!

\parbox{3cm}{line 1 \\ line 2}   or \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}line 1 \\ line 2\end{tabular]
